# Do I need to add a quote to my SQL statement?

Tags: mysql, cast-iron

This is my current statement.  It does not work.  It returns 0 results.

```
SELECT ID,ACCOUNT,Key,MasterKey, key FROM Asset 
    WHERE  MasterKey = $parent_key And Asset = $asset
```

If I change this statement to hardcoded values:

```
SELECT ID,ACCOUNT,Key,MasterKey, key FROM Asset 
    WHERE  MasterKey = '1234' And Asset = 'Test'
```

It works.

The variables are being filled using an IBM tool, Castiron.  I'm not sure if I need to consult that group, or just simply add the single quotes around the variable values.

Something like this:

```
SELECT ID,ACCOUNT,Key,MasterKey, key FROM Asset 
    WHERE  MasterKey = '''' + $parent_key + '''' And Asset = '''' + $asset + ''''
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this..Use single quotes for the variables

```
SELECT ID,ACCOUNT,Key,MasterKey, key FROM Asset WHERE MasterKey = '$parent_key' And Asset = '$asset'
```

Comment: Usually it is a good idea to expound on the code in your answer. Tell about how it works or what exactly you are doing. This helps newer developers understand exactly what is going on.

Comment: @CalebKleveter Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT ID, ACCOUNT, Key, MasterKey, key FROM Asset WHERE MasterKey = '{$parent_key}' And Asset = '{$asset}'"
```

That may help.